# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-quill' Python3

Tags: python

I am trying to run someone else's code without a requirements.txt file and it says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-quill`. I tried to do `pip install django-quill` in a virtual env but I still get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to run `pip install django-quill-editor` in order for the code to work as expected. I am still not sure why the original command did not work but this resolved the issue for me.

You can find the official setup guide for `Django quill` here: https://github.com/LeeHanYeong/django-quill-editor#setup